# rename files with sed (rearanging filenames)

Tags: bash, regex, sed, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files named like

```
some_random_str1 - Lecture X of Y some_random_str2.mp4
```

I would like to change these names to

```
Lecture X of Y - some_random_str1 some_random_str2.mp4
```

only constant pattern in names in `Lecture X of Y` where `X` and `Y` are numbers and may be different in different names

any idea for oneliner with sed or other regex tool?

Comment: With just a single example, it's impossible to know what sort of pattern you are looking for. Is there always a dash? Is the *Lecture X of Y* phrase fixed except for different X and Y values?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `rename` (Debian/ubuntu) or `prename` (RedHat/CentOS)(aka "Larry Wall's Perl rename") command from your usual repository:

```
rename -n 's/(.*) - (Lecture \d+ of \d+) (.*).mp4/$2 - $1 $3.mp4/' *.mp4
```

- `-n` is a "dry run". Remove or replace by `-v` to actually execute the command
- Assuming X and Y are numbers
- The expression can be anything Perl would accept
- Single quotes necessary around the expression to limit the use of backslashes.

Comment: funny story - I have openSUSE and this command is not working with latest `rename` version..., probably it's a good answer but how to make it work (I assume that sed will be used)

Comment: Make sure it's the right `rename`. `man rename` should give Larry Wall as the AUTHOR. Otherwise try `prename` or `perl-rename`.

Answer (score 0):

Do `cd` into the folder holding the files.
then run *(possibly with ./ replaced with a differing path, instead of cd above)* :

```
find ./ -type f  | while read n ; do  
  nn="$(
    echo "$n" | 
    sed -re 's/(.*) - (Lecture [0-9]+ of [0-9]+) (.*).mp4/\2 - \1 \3.mp4/'
  )"; 
  echo "mv '$n' '$nn'" ; 
done
```

Verify that the commands generated do look OK.

If you find all is good; run the same again, but with `| bash` appended.